Vite React App do not open default browser from terminal
I am in Mac OS Terminal.
I create a React app with npm create vite.
Then npm install and npm run dev.
Then o to open app in browser.
But it opens Chrome instead of Brave (which is my default browser).
This is an error.
Somebody knows why this happen?

Inside node_modules/vite/bin directory, there is a file named openChrome.applescript
try :
mv openChrome.applescript openChrome.applescript.bak


Awesome. The problem is fixed! Thank you!
